# How to sort records in alphabetical order in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to sort records in alphabetical order in laravel?

```
public function index()
{
    $comproducts = Comproduct::paginate(3);

    $items = Item::orderBy('name')->all();        

    return view('computer', compact(['comproducts', 'items']));

}
```

This is not working correctly. This shows

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

this error. How can i fix this?

Comment: Use `get()` instead of `all()`?

Comment: thanks bro. it works fine now

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I use `get()` instead , you can't modify query with method `all()` and also it is static function

```
  $items = Item::orderBy('name')->get();
```

Answer (score 14):

That's how you sort it, `sortBy()` comes after `all()`:

```
$items = Item::all()->sortBy('name');
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-sortby

Comment: I think this should be `sortBy()` ??

Comment: `orderBy` is to modify query and `sortBy` is to filter result so `sortBy` will work . But I think `get()` method is good to use here instead `all`

Comment: `sortBy()` is basically used to sort out the collection based on the field. And since the question has `all()`, hence I believe `sortBy()` would be better.

Answer (score 8):

Hi Please find an answer based on eloquent query laravel

Table: Users
Columns:id,name,class_id

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('class_id', [1, 2, 3])->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->paginate(50);
```

Comment: <h3><a href="{!! browse(getLocation(),$categories->id) !!}">{!! Str_limit($categories->name,100) !!} </a></h3>   Please help me to add sort function in it.

Comment: Is it in loop it's just a statement

Comment: You seem to not understand what Eloquent is. Original question was attempting to use Eloquent, you are using query builder with DB facade.

Answer (score 5):

you can do any of the following depending in the order that you wish to sort

this for ascending order

```
 $students = Student::whereId($id)->orderBy('name')->get()->all();
```

this for Descending order

```
 $students = Student::whereId($id)->orderByDesc('name')->get()->all();
```

Comment: The problem is that I get an array. For example, if I use `$students->count()` I get the following error: `Call to a member function count() on array`. :/ So it should be without `->all()` => `$students = Student::whereId($id)->orderBy('name')->get()`;