# How to get data with sorting from controller?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following query. I want to get data from the database sorted alphabetically:

```
$states = State::where('status', 1)->sortBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: It may be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246772/how-to-sort-records-in-alphabetical-order-in-laravel/47246787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which framework are you using
If `laravel` then write below syntax

```
$states = State::where('status', 1)->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [order by SQL keywords](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) to get it alphabetically ordered data as ascending or descending order. For laravel use check [Ordering, Grouping, Limit, & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) from laravel docs.

For your use case it is simple as

```
 $states = State::where('status', 1)->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

for ascending order